# Query Method URL to class convert

Tags: c#, .net, http, request, get

I want to perform a http call to a certain api and I want to pass some filters in the query:
This is a call example:

```
getCustomers?skip=0&take=20&filter=[["displayEmail1","contains","dan"],"and",["whenCreated","=","01"],"and",["customerId","=","C-00004"]]
```

I want to map the filter to a class parameter but the problem is that I have a list of two types string and list of strings. I can't map directly with ([FromQuery] CustomerQuery query) at get method in my controller.

I tried with      JsonConvert but no success.

```
var filters = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IConvertible>>(query.Filter);
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot deserialize them is that you are entering different types of data (list, string) so I am not aware of how you can fix it but what you want to achieve is easy with OData so I recommend to at least check it out [(source)](https://www.odata.org/documentation/)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, this should be a comment

Comment: As I did not have enough reputation to comment so I had to write it as answer